# How do I pass binary (blob) data from mysql to imagejpeg for a file save?

Tags: php, mysql, gd

I'm in the process of converting all my images stored in a DB to a file system structure but can't seem to save them to a file.  Here is what I'm trying.

```
....
$SQL = "SELECT thumbnail FROM profile_image WHERE user_id=7";
$r = mysql_query($SQL) or die ("Error");

$image=mysql_result($r,0,"thumbnail");

$destination = SITE_ROOT .'/photos/7/test.jpeg';

imagejpeg($image, $destination);

//header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
//echo ($image);
```

It's complaining about an invalid resource...what am I missing?

Comment: What is the **exact** error message? PS: [imagejpeg](http://nz.php.net/imagejpeg) accepts a resource as a first argument, not a string

Comment: Are you sure that given SQL query returns at least one row?

Comment: in addition to @zerkms: OP, have a look at [this function](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.imagecreatefromstring.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [imagecreatefromstring](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromstring.php) to create a valid resource.

```
// ...
if (false !== $im = imagecreatefromstring($image)) {
    imagejpeg($im, SITE_ROOT . '/photos/7/test.jpeg');
    imagedestroy($im);
}
```

Comment: `false !==` odd comparison.... `true ==` is MUCH clearer. That's kinda made me laugh. first time i've come across a statement such as that

Comment: @Flukey, following the documentation, FALSE is returned if the image type is unsupported, the data is not in a recognised format, or the image is corrupt and cannot be loaded.

Comment: Yes I know. but you could still use `true == ` it's much clearer to read than `false !==` Your way makes the code *difficult* to read. I know what the function returns.